# C# Linq All & Any working differently on blank array

Tags: c#, linq

Consider following linq example with blank array:

When `Any()` returns `false` as there is no number greater than zero how can `All()` return `true` conveying all numbers greater than zero ?

```
var arr = new int[] { };
Console.WriteLine(arr.Any(n => n > 0)); //false 
Console.WriteLine(arr.All(n => n > 0)); //true
```

Comment: Seems logical to me. _All_ numbers in `arr` are greater than zero (meaning there is _no_ number _not_ greater than zero), and there is _no_ number in `arr` that is greater than zero.

Comment: The documentation for both clearly state this is the expected results for empty sequences.

Comment: @juharr I think the question is more about _why_ it's implemented like that (which of course can be explained consequently by boolean logic).

Comment: This is called [Vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Seems logical to me.

- `All`: Are *all* numbers in `arr` greater than zero (meaning there is *no* number *not* greater than zero) => `true`
- `Any`: Is there *any* number in `arr` that is greater than zero => `false`

But more important, according to [Boolean Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra):

```
arr.All(n => n > 0);
```

gives `true`, because it should be the **logical opposite** of

```
arr.Any(n => !(n > 0));
```

which gives `false` (actually this is what the above two points say).

Comment: Code level implementation i understand , but logically it was not making sense to me. Your above point cleared it out ! thanks

Comment: I really like this answer for pointing out the logical relationship between `All` and `Any` (i.e. that they satisfy [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)).

Comment: Another example, probably simpler and more day-to-day: imagine there is an empty room. Ok, with "all" the question would be like "all of the people in the room are female?" and the answer would be yes, because there is no one, so "all" of them are female. With "any" the question is "is there at least a female in the room?", for which the answer is obviously no.
Another way to put it: with "all" the number of female people should be the same as the total number of people (0 == 0 is still correct), whereas with "any" the number of female should be > 1.

Comment: @Kyle De Morgan's laws was what I actually thought of when adding the link to boolean algebra, but I just couldn't remember the name...

Comment: The boolean logic or De Morgan makes no sense here since `Any(n => n > 0)` and `Any(n => n <= 0)` yields same result as happen to `All` too. Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 26):

The implementation of `All` shows very clearly why.

```
    public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            if (!predicate(element)) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

It runs a `foreach` over the collection. If there are no elements in the collection, it will skip the `foreach` and will return true.

Interestingly, the implementation on `Any`

```
    public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
        foreach (TSource element in source) {
            if (predicate(element)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This cleary shows they're opposites.

Answer (score 6):

[The implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs) for `All` returns true if no element is in the list:

```
public static bool All<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    if (predicate == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    foreach (TSource element in source) {
        if (!predicate(element)) return false;
    }
    return true;  // watch this
}
```

This seems quite counter-intuitive, but that´s how it is implemented.

However the docs are quite clear for the return-value of [`All`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548541(v=vs.110).aspx):

> true if every element of the source sequence passes the test in the
>   specified predicate, **or if the sequence is empty**;

Answer (score 5):

A bit of mathematical perspective:
`Any` and `All` are generalized versions of `||` and `&&` operators, just as `Sum` and `Product` (not in LINQ) are generalizations of `+` and `*`.

Generalized operators when working on empty set return [neutral element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) of the operation. For `+`  this is 0, for `*` this is 1 so `emptyArray.Product() == 1` because 1 is neutral element of `*` operation (for all a: `a * 1 == a`), for `||` this is `false` (`a || false == a`) and for `&&` this is `true` (`a || true == a`).

Thanks to this generalized operators preserve associativity of the "original" operation, e.g. for Sum: `intersect(A,B) == EmptySet; S = union(A,B); S.Sum() == A.Sum() + B.Sum()`, and this will work even when one of the sets `A` or `B` is empty. In other words it is mathematically convenient to define that generalized operator on empty set returns neutral element.